# AngularJS : data binding not working as expected using a service

Tags: angularjs, service

I'm having trouble with services in AngularJS.
Being a newbie it's probably something crucial I'm missing here.

The title {{p01g.visiteTitel}} isn't magically refreshing but keeps displaying "sometitle".

The ng-repeat is working as expected.

(dataFactory is a service that connects to a remote server using $resource)

My service :

```
myApp.service('p00Service', ['dataFactory', function(dataFactory) {

    var service = this;

    service.visites = [];
    service.visiteAantal = 0;
    service.visiteTitel = "sometitle";

    service.findVisites = function (datum) {

        dataFactory.get({verb: "search", q: datum}, function (data) {
            angular.copy(data.visites, service.visites);
            service.visiteAantal = service.visites.length;
            if (service.visiteAantal === 0) {
                service.visiteTitel = "geen visites op " + datum
            } else if (service.visiteAantal === 1) {
                service.visiteTitel = "1 visite op " + datum
            } else {
                service.visiteTitel = service.visiteAantal + " visites op " + datum
            }
        });

    };

}]);
```

My controller :

```
myApp.controller('p01gCtrl', ['p00Service', function (p00Service) {

    var vm = this;

    var datum = moment();  //I'm using moment.js -> moment() is date of today

    p00Service.findVisites(datum);

    vm.visites = p00Service.visites;
    vm.visiteTitel = p00Service.visiteTitel;

}]);
```

My HTML :

```
<div class="p01g" ng-controller="p01gCtrl as p01g">

    <div class="well_grey" style="min-height:40px;max-height:40px;max-width:330px">

        <p style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">

                {{p01g.visiteTitel}}

        </p>

    </div>

    <div class="well" style="min-height:190px;max-height:190px;max-width:330px">

        <table style="width:100%;line-height:40px">

                <tbody ng-repeat="visite in p01g.visites">

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:20%;line-height:40px;padding-left:7px"><span style="font-size:16px">{{visite.t133datum | date:"dd/MM/yy"}}</span></td>
                        <td style="width:60%;line-height:40px;text-align:center"><span style="font-size:16px">{{visite.t133achternaam}}</span></td>
                        <td style="width:20%;line-height:40px;padding-left:30px"><span style="font-size:16px">{{visite.t133classificatie}}</span></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: If you have more information about what `dataFactory` looks like, then it will be easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code exactly and created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8a80GJY7QyMuyJaM99Hm?p=info) and added my own `dataFactory` to return sample data and there are no errors and the data is getting bound fine, so I believe the issue is in your implementation of `dataFactory`, or the way you are calling it (make sure it's expecting a callback function, since that is what you are passing it).

**Edit:** Here is a new [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rds6J8YxY4rkgivBLP9y?p=info) with updated code that I believe reproduces your issue. So the reason why the title is not getting updated is because

```
vm.visiteTitel = p00Service.visiteTitel;
```

is setting `vm.visiteTitel` to the value of the string in `p00Service.visiteTitel`, but it is **NOT** getting a reference to `p00Service.visiteTitel`, so if you update `visiteTitel` in your  `p00Service` after this assignment (which is happening in this case because the `$resource` callback is async), then it has no effect on `vm.visiteTitel`.

One way to make this work would be to pass a callback to `p00Service` to update your controller values like so:

```
p00Service.findVisites(datum, function(visites, visiteTitel) {
    vm.visites = visites;
    vm.visiteTitel = visiteTitel;
});
```

and then update your service to call this callback after the data is loaded:

```
service.visites = [];
service.visiteAantal = 0;
service.visiteTitel = "sometitle";

service.findVisites = function (datum, callback) {

    dataFactory.get({}, function (data) {
    ...

        if(callback) {
            callback(service.visites, service.visiteTitel);
        }
    });

};
```

This code can be cleaned up a bit, but here is a workable [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gncuz085AwwjXiPLSkTj?p=info) demonstrating `vm.visites` and `vm.visiteTitel` getting updated correctly.

Comment: @GDM_70 I updated my answer where I reproduced the problem and gave  a potential solution.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I could never solve this one on my own ! Now I understand what is happening, you saved my day (week...)

Answer (score 0):

the dataFactory looks like this :

```
myApp.factory("dataFactory", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/vf/rest/visites/:verb", {}, {
        get: {method: "GET", isArray: false, cache: false}
    });
}]);
```